# BATCH script - FOR loop stops on IF test

Tags: git, batch-file

I try to parse files in git revisions and take an action upon their status

For some reason after my 'if then goto' , the loop does not go on any further while it does without that branching test

the whole script :

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET max=10
set "TAB=   "

REM parse N revision

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('git rev-list --max-count=%max% HEAD') DO (

    REM parse all modifs in this revision

    ECHO Checking revision %%a 

    FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r %%a') do (

    rem echo b %%b

    set string=%%b

    rem echo string !string!

    set status=!string:~0,1!
    set filename=!string:~2!

    echo %TAB%Filename: '!filename!'
    echo %TAB%Status: !status!

    IF "!status!"=="A" GOTO :CASE_A
    IF "!status!"=="M" GOTO :CASE_M
    IF "!status!"=="D" GOTO :CASE_D

    :CASE_A
        echo added
    :CASE_M
        echo modified
    :CASE_D
        echo deleted

############## LOOPS STOPS HERE ###############

    )
)
```

explanations :

```
git rev-list --max-count=%max% HEAD
```

returns 2 lines containing revisions hash

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r %%a
```

will check all files in that revision

for instance:

```
A       New Text Document.txt
M       test.bat
```

I am busting my head against this one, if anyone knows how to fix this
thanks

Comment: Your issue appears to be because you've used `:Labels` within the `For` loop construct, which you cannot do!

Comment: Even if your Labels were not within a loop, the code would not work as expected, because 1. you don't handle the case of no match, and 2. execution falls from one Label section into the next, because you do not leave them (note that for batch files, commands are executed one after another, unless you explicitly instruct not to do so).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment you cannot use `:Labels` within the `For` loop construct.

Instead just use parenthesised blocks:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Max=10"
Set "Tab=   "

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('git rev-list --max-count=%Max% HEAD') Do (
    Echo Checking revision %%A 
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r %%A') Do (
        Set "String=%%~B"
        Echo %Tab%FileName: '!String:~2!'
        Echo %Tab%Status: !String:~,1!
        If /I "!String:~,1!"=="A" (
            Echo Added
        )
        If /I "!String:~,1!"=="M" (
            Echo Modified
        )
        If /I "!String:~,1!"=="D" (
            Echo Deleted
        )
    )
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set max=10
set "TAB=   "

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
    'git rev-list --max-count=%max% HEAD'
) do (
    echo Checking revision %%A
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%B in (
        'git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r %%A'
    ) do call :case_do "%%~B" "%%~C"
)

goto :case_done

:case_do
    setlocal
    set "status=%~1"
    set "filename=%~2"

    echo %TAB%Status: %status%
    echo %TAB%Filename: '%filename%'

    if "%status%" == "A" goto :case_A
    if "%status%" == "M" goto :case_M
    if "%status%" == "D" goto :case_D
    goto :case_else
exit /b
    :case_A
    echo added
exit /b
    :case_M
    echo modified
exit /b
    :case_D
    echo deleted
exit /b
    :case_else
    echo fixme
exit /b
:case_done
```

Based on the case idea.

1. The 1st `for` loop gets each revision as `%%A` and prints it.
2. The nested `for` loop gets the status as `%%B` and filename as `%%C`.
3. Label `:case_do` is called with `"%%~B"` and `"%%~C"` as arguments.
4. Optional `setlocal` is used in label `:case_do` to keep set variables as local scope.
5. `status` is assigned the value of 1st argument.
6. `filename` is assigned the value of 2nd argument.
7. Prints names and values of the 2 variables.
8. Compares `%status%` to the each of `A M D` and goes to the label of the match.
9. If not any of `A M D`, it goes to the optional `:case_else`.
10. When a case ends, execution returns to the caller in the `for` loop.
11. Once the `for` loops have finished, the `goto :case_done` will end that section.

No variable substitution done as tokens set in the nested `for` loop should be good
with the example output posted in the question.

No delayed expansion required in this code example.